# Retrieve a record with fromdate and todate by passing single date in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, datetime, hql

Here I have a Database Table with fromDate and toDate field. My requirement is to retrieve all records with a specific date(it can be either fromDate or toDate or in between fromDate and toDate).

TableName: MyTable

[image]

I need to find a record with date 13/2/2015 (it can be either fromDate or toDate or in between fromDate and toDate). What will be the query to find such record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) clause. Assuming from and to dates are inclusive, you would write:

```sql
SELECT ...
WHERE '2015-02-13' BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate
```

Comment: HQL for this query is bit confusing: 
`"from MyTable mT where selectDate BETWEEN mT.fromDate AND mT.toDate"

selectDate - param
mT.fromDate and mT.toDate - database table column`

Is this the right HQL for your query?

Comment: what if I have two dates to search in between fromDate and toDate. I tried like this
`SELECT * FROM test.sample where '2014-11-10' or '2014-11-18' BETWEEN FROM_DATE and TO_DATE;
` 
not working

Comment: @tvshajeer try this, `SELECT * FROM test.sample where '2014-11-10'  BETWEEN FROM_DATE and TO_DATE or  '2014-10-16'  BETWEEN FROM_DATE and TO_DATE;`